# PHP get previous link ID

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am fetching all records from a db table into a page using;

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

The page displays a summary of car details:

[image: car-list]

Now the idea is to create another page that will load the full content of each car. The issue is that I have no idea how to do it. I have searched on the internet but i dont get any results and i am new to php.

MYSQL query would be something like;

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = {$clicked-id}
```

where clicked id is the previous clicked car. i guess i have to assign an id to each previous car title.

I am quite lost, can someone please help me.

Comment: I would not assign an id for each car but a url, so you can pass that to the query and not a number, keep its SEO so like: `SELECT * from cars_table WHERE url="fordfocus"` so your links look like `site.com/details/fordfocus`

Comment: On a separate note, it is most likely that you don't need to `SELECT *`. Although this may just be a test it is good to learn good habits immediatly and only select what you really need.

Comment: @Lawrence That isn't going to work as 'fordfocus' isn't going to be unique. You are better of passing the unique primary key. Pretty URLs and SEO should come much later in the development process.

Comment: removed unnecessary link

Comment: @meagar you can build your table so that the `url` field is unique, I don't see any problem in doing this at an early stage.

Comment: @cambraca each to there own ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone exactly my point :)

Comment: @cambraca These appear to be user-submitted listings, meaning it would be up to the *user* to come up with a unique URL for *their* Ford Focus vs the countless other listings for *identical cars*. There is not *one* Ford Focus in the world. Generating unique SEO-friendly URLs for user-submitted content is a feature to add to the system *on top* of base functionality. Typically you would do something like Stack Overflow; the URL still contains the unique numeric ID and a textual SEO-friendly slug.

Comment: i can use a composite key for friendly seo, so make, model and unique primary key

Comment: More plainly: SEO sits on top of the app. The database is the lowest level of the app. Trying to incorporate SEO into the modeling of your data relationships is mixing two completely unrelated concepts and is dead wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php), it's very helpful.

Basically the link should be something like:

```
<a href="/detail.php?id=<?= $car_id ?>"> car info .. </a>
```

So you pass the clicked id in the `id` parameter.

Then, in your detail page, you retrieve it like this:

```
<?php
  $car_id = $_GET['id'];
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id = '.intval($car_id);
?>
```

I'm using `$_GET` here because the parameter came in the URL. Again, check out the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php), it's very helpful with this early stuff.

Note that I used `intval` to keep [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) off my back. You should research about it if you don't know what it means. The basic idea here is to prevent a user from calling something like `detail.php?id=1;DROP TABLE cars;`, which, if not using `intval`, would make your query:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id = 1;DROP TABLE cars;
```

Which would destroy your data.

Comment: I'll upvote this answer if you prove that your link is helpful for the particular question asked.

Comment: You mean the PHP Manual link? It's a link to the main PHP docs. In my opinion the OP should read the first chapters, which contain the basics of using the language. In this particular case he needs to read about superglobals (`$_GET`, etc.), but I think it's better if he reads the whole thing..

Comment: Okay, -1 then, though the rest of the answer is okay.

Comment: Thanks, its working now, im going to look into securing it against sql injections, what does the intval do?

Comment: [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) converts to an integer, so if you have something like `intval("12 horses")`, it will become just `12`

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into `$_GET` variable in PHP. This "special" variable allows you to get parameters passed in the URL,

With this, you will be able pass parameters in the URL, like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/showcar.php?id=5
```

And then, you can get the value of the specified `id` with `$_GET['id']`.

See more information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here is the markup that is rendered from your second car on the list:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" rowspan="3" style="padding: 8px 15px 0px 0px;"><img src=
        "car-images/2_main.jpg" class="car-list" /></td>

        <td valign="top" colspan="4">
          <h2>MG ZR</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td valign="top" colspan="4">3 Door Hatchback, Yellow, Petrol, Manual, Drivers
        airbag, 1 owner from new, Folding rear seats, Sports seats, Trip computer, Front
        electric windows, Alarm.service history,ABS,cd player,power steering,remote
        central locking</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td valign="bottom">
          <h4 class="car-info">Fuel</h4>Petrol
        </td>

        <td valign="bottom">
          <h4 class="car-info">Miles</h4>85000
        </td>

        <td valign="bottom">
          <h4 class="car-info">Year</h4>2006
        </td>

        <td valign="bottom">
          <h4 class="car-info">Price</h4>&Acirc;&pound;7500
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lets assume you want to click on the image to view the details. You will need to wrap an anchor tag around the image, for example:

```
...
<a href="deatils.php?carId=2"><img src="car-images/2_main.jpg" class="car-list" /></a>
...
```

That `carId=2` needs to come from whatever code is generating your `<div id="car-list">` markup.

Then of course you will need a page to receive that detail in the URL named details.php (per my example), and parse the `carId=2` like this `$id = $_GET['carId']`. You can then query the database as you have stated using the `$id` variable.

Answer (score -1):

When you click a car, PHP needs to know what car you clicked. For example, the overview page is at `www.example.com/cars`. Make a link to the car detail page on every car: `www.example.com/viewcar?id=1`. Here is 1 the id of the car in the database.

On the `viewcar` page, you can get the id with `$_GET['id']`. Use this value in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE id = $_GET['id'];
```

**NOTE** Beware that this solution illustrates the concept, but should not be used because this is very vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: What's the point in posting solutions which should not be used?

Comment: I'd prefer a click on the downvote button rather than on my comment

Comment: The question refers to very common 'problem', which can be solved with many solutions. I try to give a quite complete answer to help the OP a bit on the way. Why aren't you just happy that I mention this pitfall, since all answers in this thread refer to injection `$_GET` into the query.

Comment: I cannot be happy when I see mutual exclusive paragraphs, "Use this value"..."it should not be used". Try to make your mind up first.

Answer (score -2):

Simple. When you build the link to the "Detail view" of a car, add a parameter, for example:

```
<a href="detailview.php?carid=12">Detail view</a>
```

Now in the detailView.php, you can make the SQL Query using the paramenter, like this

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ".$_GET["carid"];
    ...
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, it is. But thats a different matter. I just illustrate here the mechanism to use URL parameters to send data to another page. I think security is too wide of a issue to discuss it here.

Comment: The quality of the answer is the matter. Post usable code or don't post anything.